# Value from shared preferences isen't updating

Tags: flutter, dart, save, sharedpreferences

I have a function which gets data from shared preferences. I have this function in a seperat file, in which only this function is. The function is called by pressing a button. The data from shared preferences should be printed in the command prompt. The problem is that when I press the butten only one time, the value is 0. When I press the button for a secon time, the value is the expected value.

This is the code where I call the function:

```
RaisedButton(
   child: Text("Get Data"),
   onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
        getDataString();
     });
     print(dayStatistic);
   },
  ),
```

This is the code where I get the data:

```
Future<String> getDataString() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  dayStatistic =
      prefs.getStringList('dayStatistic').map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some issues with your code. Try this.

```
RaisedButton(
   child: Text("Get Data"),
   onPressed: () async {
     final val = await getDataString();
     setState(() {
        dayStatistic = val;
     });
     print(val);
   },
  ),
```

```
Future<List> getDataString() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final dayStatistic =
        prefs.getStringList('dayStatistic').map((i) => int.parse(i)).toList();
    return dayStatistic;
  }
```